# How to dynamically add LinearLayout on top of the TextView

Tags: android, layout

I have an application in which I am generating a relative layout, which contains two text views, and below it I am generating a linear layout. I want that layout to be on top of the relative layout, but nothing is happening. Please help me to sort it out. My snippet is below.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;

            LinearLayout relativeLayout1 = null;

            holder.text_data_for_Name.removeAllViews();
            for (Region object : temp.phonelist.regionList)

            {

                relativeLayout1 = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                relativeLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                final TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());

                TextView tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
                tv1.setText(object.getCCInfoLeft());
                lprams.setMargins(0, 0, 300, 0);
                tv1.setLayoutParams(lprams);

                tv1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
                tv1.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 5);
                tv1.setId(1);
                relativeLayout.addView(tv1);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    tv2.setText(object.getCCInfoRight());
                    // newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
                    newParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

                    tv2.setLayoutParams(newParams);
                    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
                    tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 20, 5);
                    tv2.setId(2);
                    relativeLayout.addView(tv2);





                textView[2] = new TextView(getContext());

            relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            textView[2].setText("");

            textView[2].setText(object.getCCInfoShortDesc());
            //textView[2].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            textView[2].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10);
                String layoutDetail = object.getCCInfoShortDescAlign();
            if (layoutDetail.equals("BL")) {
                //relativeLayout1.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
                linearLayout.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT);
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, relativeLayout.getId());
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);//, relativeLayoutParams);

                 relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("BR")) {
                linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 13, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, relativeLayout.getId());
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("TL")) 
            {
                linearLayout.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 20);

                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, relativeLayout.getId());

                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);

            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("TR")) {
                linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 13, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);//, relativeLayoutParams);
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, relativeLayout.getId());
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                 relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
            }

            holder.tex
```

t_data_for_Name.addView(relativeLayout);

Comment: try by creating linear layout before Two textViews and name your LinearLayout linearlayout instead of relativeLayout1

Comment: two textViews are inside LinearLayout or outside..

Comment: @  Nepster outside the linear layout inside the relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;
        LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

        int linearId=11;
        holder.text_data_for_Name.removeAllViews();
        for (Region object : temp.phonelist.regionList) {

            relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setId(linearId++);

            textView[2] = new TextView(getContext());
            textView[2].setText("");
            textView[2].setText(object.getCCInfoShortDesc());
            textView[2].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv1prams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv2prams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            final TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
            tv1.setText(object.getCCInfoLeft());
            tv1prams.setMargins(0, 0, 300, 0);
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            tv1.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 5);
            tv1.setId(linearId++);


            tv2.setText(object.getCCInfoRight());
            tv2prams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 20, 5);
            tv2.setId(linearId++);

            String layoutDetail = object.getCCInfoShortDescAlign();
            if (layoutDetail.equals("BL")) {
                //relativeLayout1.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
                linearLayout.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT);
                linearLayoutprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);//, relativeLayoutParams);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,linearLayout.getId());
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,linearLayout.getId());
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("BR")) {
                linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 13, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
                linearLayoutprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,linearLayout.getId());
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,linearLayout.getId());
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("TL")) {
                linearLayout.setPadding(13, 5, 5, 20);
                linearLayoutprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,linearLayout.getId());
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,linearLayout.getId());
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            } else if (layoutDetail.equals("TR")) {
                linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 13, 20);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);//, relativeLayoutParams);
                linearLayoutprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                linearLayout.addView(textView[2]);
                relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,linearLayout.getId());
                tv1prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,linearLayout.getId());
                tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            }
            tv2prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,tv1.getId());
            tv1.setLayoutParams(tv1prams);
            relativeLayout.addView(tv1);

            tv2.setLayoutParams(tv2prams);
            relativeLayout.addView(tv2);
        }
```

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana i update my ques plzz see to it,there are certain conditions according to which i have to set layout

Comment: right now it is giving me layout only on the top,but i want it in the bottom too

Comment: i am checking condtion through BR that means bottom left,BR- Bottom right,TL-top left and so on..according to this i have to generate the layout

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana in this textview on right side get overlap on left side textview

Comment: @  Haresh Chhelana sry to bother you bt some of my values are not visible now

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: now when app runs data that i getting from model class row that contain single data get invisible,i mean single roe is not get visible

Comment: I thinnk you have to debug it and let know where you can get exactly problem.

Comment: i debug it,i am getting all the values during dubuging and in log also m getting values.but not in textview and also right side textview's widht is getting decrease in each row and its height gets increase

Comment: okay can you please comment setMargin and setPadding line in code.

Comment: ok i did but still the same not getting single row values,layout that you made top and bottom on condititon checking is working perfectly fine and also displaying each values but other layout is not

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the relativeLayoutParams to relativeLayout1.

```
relativeLayout1.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams)
```

Hope it work.